# Keyboard shortcut to navigate Back Forward in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts, back

In Eclipse, we can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> to navigate Back, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> to navigate Forward.

Is this shortcut available in Notepad++?
If no, can it be installed using plugins?

Comment: What do you mean by navigating back and forward?

Comment: It goes to Previous/Next position in Editor History in Eclipse - http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html#shortcuts_navigation

Answer (score 46):

There's a plug-in [Location Navigate](https://sourceforge.net/projects/locationnav/), which enables you to navigate between your last edit/view points.

> ..Can use shortcut (ctrl + - for back position and ctrl + shift + - for forward position) to jump code back and forward..

The plug-in [SourceCookifier](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/) comes with a navigation history,
but it only remembers the jumps between symbols.

> Navigate Backward (Alt + Left)
>
> Navigate Forward (Alt + Right)

Comment: I'd like to use LocationNav but I'm unsure how to. I put the dll in plugins dir and restarted notepad++, but no new plugin shows up under the plugins drop-down, and the ctrl + / ctrl -  hotkeys don't work. QAny ideas?

Comment: @Amalgovinus you can install it from within notepad++. `plugins` -> `plugin manager` -> `show plugin manager`

Comment: Sadly LocationNav is only supported for 32bit

Comment: Forward and backward navigation should be in core, not a plugin.

Comment: In my 64bit windows system, LocationNav works perfectly.

Comment: now the notepad++ does not ship with the plugin manager. how to install the SourceCookifier then @_@

Comment: There is a 64bit LocationNav Dll, which can be download from here:[JetNpp / LocationNavigate](https://github.com/JetNpp/LocationNavigate), it works OK on Notepad++ 7.9.1 64bit.

Comment: It seems that `SourceCookifier` is just for **C#**  files?! if yes, you have to revise your answer and explicitly mention this huge limitation or remove that as first option because the user does not ask for c#!

Comment: LocationNav works in a single file if I need to search for different locations.

Comment: @elig Since version v0.4.7.8 there's an official x64 build of the plugin: https://sourceforge.net/projects/locationnav/files/. The plugin is also installable using Notepad++'s built-in Plugins Admin.